# Material disappears while object is deselected

Tags: modeling, materials

Basically when I have the object selected it looks perfect and the moment I select anything else it vanishes, this only happens in material view and rendered view, I have absolutely no clue what I could have done to cause this.

[image: selected]

[image: not selected]

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshots it appears you're seeing the OpenGL masking effect.

The pink container's outer walls are semmi transparent and masking the portion of gray plate that's behind it.

Parent the outer container to the gray plate then unparent it again.  (child = pink container)

If that doesn't fix it, try ticking/unticking both objects' "Transparency" box. That's in the properties (cube icon) at right, way down to the "Display" tab.